# run time error. automation error. the remote procedure call failed

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I wrote below code to sort an excel column like:

```
Sub deneme()
Workbooks("macro.xlsm").Activate
    
Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
excelApp.Visible = False

excelApp.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\cildi\Desktop\sortdeneme\New\new.xlsx"

Dim excelsWbk As Object    
Set excelsWbk = excelApp.Workbooks("new.xlsx")  

excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
    :=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

But I get the error "run time error. automation error. the remote procedure call failed"
at the line:

```
excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
    :=Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

I search but cannot find any solution.

[image: error image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Range("A2")` needs to be qualified: `excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")` - also, make sure `excelsWbk` was properly set to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Still same error :(

Comment: Why do you open a new Excel instance?

Comment: Does that mean you verified `excelsWbk` does not equal `Nothing`?

Comment: Because I want to use "excelApp.Visible = False" method. I want to run the macro in the background.

Comment: @braX yes. I assigned the opened "new.xlsx" (opened in the code: "excelApp.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\cildi\Desktop\sortdeneme\New\new.xlsx") to the excelsWbk here.

Comment: The error can happen if there is no Autofilter applied. For `excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.....` to work, there should already be an autofilter in place... else you will get `Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set` as it cannot find the Autofilter.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for comment. Autofilter is already applied at row 2.

Comment: Strange. AFAIK that is the only way you will get that error on that line. Can you put a breakpoint at `excelsWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter...` and then manually check if the file which opened has autofilter in `Sheet1`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes. I added the error image to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I detect a mistake of mine. I opened the "new.xlsx" file befor the code run. Sorry for taking your time.

In that case, I get another error at the same line:
run time error 
automation error 
the remote procedure call failed

Comment: Could you share what you are trying to do? Just sort by column `A`? Is there any code after `End With`? I mean you need to `Save` and `Close` the workbook and `Quit` the Excel instance. Please, do clarify. Btw, using `excelApp.Visible = True` will help you when developing the code. Only when it is functioning properly (the Excel instance is closed (quit)), out-comment the line. You don't need it since `False` is the default value.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for answer. Yes, I just want to sort column A. No code after `End With`. I manually kill excel in windows task manager because code gives error before reach `save`, `close` and `quit`, I will add them later. Macro should be run in the background so `excelApp.Visible = False`. I get your advice, for now, I set `excelApp.Visible = True`. I get the error: run time error automation error the remote procedure call failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Another Excel Instance

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HiddenSort()
    Const ProcName As String = "HiddenSort"
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\cildi\Desktop\sortdeneme\New\"
    Const fName As String = "new.xlsx"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SortColumn As Long = 1
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = Workbooks(fName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not twb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The file '" & fName & "' in folder '" & FolderPath _
            & "' is already open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim xlApp As Object: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True ' just out-comment, don't use 'False'.
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim wb As Object: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & fName)
    
    Dim ws As Object: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim krg As Range: Set krg = rg.Columns(SortColumn)
    
    rg.Sort Key1:=krg, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set wb = Nothing ' prevent 'Run-time error '-2147417848': Automation error'
    
SafeExit:
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    xlApp.Quit

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```